# Convert datatable column values in a comma separated string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable who has only one column with values as below

```
    COLUMN1

      a

      b

      c

      d
```

So what I want is, I want this values in a string with comma separated like below

`string value = a,b,c,d`

How will I get this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var list = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["COLUMN1"].ToString());
string value = string.Join(",", list);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1